# Which is suitable way to create DataFrame using JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spak 1.6.2

Which is suitable way to create dataframe from RDBMS table:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();
```

or

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().jdbc(url, table, properties);
```

Comment: Under hood it knock same door, but for flexibility and further usage perspective I'd suggest first approach

Comment: Both the ways are fine, but second one is more concise !